# how regular expression starts from dot

Tags: regex, preg-match

My string is `Car.audi=true` I wanna select `audi` alone. If i use `.` regular expression take it as any single character. How do I match string?

Comment: read about `*` `+` and other quantifers

Comment: `\.\K\w+` .............

Answer (score -1):

In order to accept a special character as a literal in regular expressions, you must usually place the character in a character class. This may vary by implementation but generally, the regex `[.]` will match a single literal period character.

Alternatively you may escape the period with a backslash, as in the regex `\.` which should also match a literal dot.